# Why is the fetch function running twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, next.js, fetch

Every time an user wants to create a new product the fetch function runs twice. I tried adding a console.log when the user clicks on the button, and it only returns once but the fetch still runs twice.

**Fetch Function**:

```js
function handleSubmitNewItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dataToInsert = {
      product_name: newItem.product_name,
      sku: newItem.sku,
      description: newItem.description,
      product_type: newItem.product_type,
      available_stock: parseInt(newItem.available_stock),
      cost: parseFloat(newItem.cost),
      selling_price: parseFloat(newItem.selling_price),
    };
    const submitNewItem = () =>
      fetch("/api/inventario?newItem=true", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(dataToInsert),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        // Revalidate productList data. Reset state of editingItemId
        .then(() => {
          mutate(productList);
          setNewItem(newItemInitialState);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          throw error;
        });

    toast.promise(submitNewItem, {
      loading: "Loading",
      success: "Success",
      error: "Error",
    });
```

**Form code**:

```js
             <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmitEditItem(e)}>
                <div className="flex flex-row justify-between border-b border-gray-200 px-2.5 py-5 sm:px-7">
                  <input
                    className={`inpt-primary w-full sm:w-3/4 ${
                      !editingItemId && "font-bold"
                    } text-base disabled:p-0 md:disabled:text-[1.5rem]`}
                    value={selectedItem?.product_name}
                    required
                    placeholder={`Escribe el nombre del producto`}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                      setSelectedItem({
                        ...selectedItem,
                        product_name: event.target.value,
                      });
                    }}
                    disabled={editingItemId !== selectedItem.id}
                  />
                  <div
                    className={`${
                      editingItemId ? "hidden" : ""
                    } flex cursor-pointer flex-row items-center gap-4 text-slate-500`}
                  >
                    <HiOutlinePencilAlt
                      size={24}
                      onClick={() => setEditingItemId(selectedItem.id)}
                    />
                    <IoCloseSharp
                      size={24}
                      onClick={() => setSelectedItem({})}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex-grow px-2.5 py-9 sm:px-7">
                  <h3 className="text-sm font-medium md:text-base">
                    Información del producto
                  </h3>
                  <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-2 py-4  text-sm text-gray-500 sm:w-[400px]">
                    {selectedProductInfo.map((item, key) => {
                      const isEditing = editingItemId === selectedItem.id;
                      return (
                        <label
                          key={key}
                          className="grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-2 py-1 pr-3.5"
                        >
                          {isEditing ? (
                            <div
                              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                __html: !item.required
                                  ? item.title
                                  : `${item.title}<span class='text-red-500'> *</span>`,
                              }}
                            ></div>
                          ) : (
                            item.title
                          )}
                          <input
                            name={item.handle}
                            value={
                              item.handle === "cost" ||
                              item.handle === "selling_price"
                                ? isEditing
                                  ? selectedItem[item.handle]
                                  : formatter.format(selectedItem[item.handle])
                                : selectedItem[item.handle] ?? ""
                            }
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              handleOnchangeSelectedItem(e, item)
                            }
                            className={`inpt-primary !py-1 invalid:ring-red-500`}
                            required
                            disabled={!isEditing}
                          />
                        </label>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  className={`${
                    editingItemId !== selectedItem.id ? "hidden" : ""
                  } flex justify-between border-t border-gray-200 px-7 py-5 text-sm`}
                >
                  <span className="text-xs italic text-red-500">
                    Campos Obligatorios (*)
                  </span>

                  <div className="flex gap-2">
                    <button
                      className="btn-secondary"
                      onClick={handleCancelEditItem}
                    >
                      Cancelar
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn-primary"
                    >
                      Guardar
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Is this an issue with Sonner or is something wrong with my code?

I also checked the mutate function from SWR but I doubt that's the issue because the url shows '/api/inventario?**newItem=true**'

[image: Newtok Tab Image]

Comment: Doesn't look like handleSubmitNewItem is ever actually called or attached to anything in your JSX, so I don't know how the fetch is being fired at all; is there more code  you've forgotten to include in your example?

Comment: Try to collaborate narrowing your question down removing all the sugar. It's not really clear what is specifically `toast` for instance and how it behaves.